# c# Get main form WindowMainHandle

Tags: c#

When there are multiple forms of one window app,
I want to get the parent WindowMainHandle. (Main Form)

The problem is that when the child form is selected, I get the child WindowMainHandle.

how should i solve it?

Process[] viewProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName(Application.ProductName);
IntPtr hWndOfPrevInstance = viewProcesses[0].MainWindowHandle;

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702976/winforms-main-window-handle